# Verifying and then displaying data from a database in HTML using php on click of a button

Tags: php, html, mysql

What i was trying to do is , enter data in the text field click the " Track product" button and then verifying the value entered from a database and if the value exists, displaying some other data from the table in the same page.

Here is the code that i did:

```html
<div class="wrapper col1">
  <div id="container">
    <form>
 <h3>Enter Your Track_ID</h3><input type="text" name="trk_id">
 <input type="submit" action="tracking.html" value="Track Product" name="track" method="post">
 </form>
   
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper col2">

  <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test_drive2016";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL FROM employees WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID=$_POST['track']";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if($row[EMPLOYEE_ID]!=null){
echo $row[EMPLOYEE_ID].'</br>'.'<h2>'.'Your poduct is on Process'.'</h2>';
}
?>

</div>
```

And this the result i get -_-.
Lot of stuff might be wrong, take those into consideration.

Comment: that means your where condition `WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID=$_POST['track']` isn't matching any records. check and verify the same.

Comment: this happens before i enter any value in the text field. so what i think is a issue with declaring variables in my code

Comment: Yes, there are lots of stuff wrong with your code. 1- `<input>` elements do not have `action` attribute. `action` attribute is for <form>` element 2- you have to check if the form is posted or not, otherwise your php section will generate errors. 3- the name of the `<input>` element in your `html` is `trk_id` but you are using `$_POST['track']` in your php. 4- you are creating a resultset named `$result ` but never fetch data from it in an array named `$row`

Comment: was useful but not yet close to expectation. corrected this stuffs , but no luck.